# Flutter - Remove Content Type from DioError response

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dio

How may I only show the message provided by the DioError Content?

For example instead of this:

> `DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: User not found!`

I only want to show:

> `User not found!`

Here's the dio interceptor code:

```
  dio.interceptors
  ..add(InterceptorsWrapper(
    onRequest: (RequestOptions options) {
      print("Dio Request");
      print(options.headers);
      print(options.data);
      print(options.contentType);
      print(options.extra);
      print(options.baseUrl + "" + options.path);
      return options;
    },
    onResponse: (Response response) {
      print("Dio Success Response");
      print(response.data);
      print(response.extra);
      return response;
    },
    onError: (DioError e) async {
      print("Dio Error Response");
      print(e.response);
      print(e.message);
      print(e.type);
      await _errorResponseCheck(e);
    },
  ))

  _errorResponseCheck(DioError e) {
    if (e.response.data["message"] != null) {
      throw HttpException(e.response?.data["message"]?.toString());
    } else {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `e.message` will give you the error message.

Comment: Or just get the error like this `print(e.message.split(":").last);`

Comment: Now I updated my answer, please take a look at it. Maybe it'll help you now.

Answer (score 2):

For instance, you are getting exceptions with response like this below

```
I/flutter (19222): DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400]
I/flutter (19222): uri: https://www.example.com/forgotpassword
I/flutter (19222): statusCode: 400
I/flutter (19222): Response Text:
I/flutter (19222): {"success":false,"message":"Invalid mail id"}
```

You can get the error message from the `response` of `DioError`.

```
on DioError catch (e) {
  final base = BaseModel.fromJson(e.response.data);
  if (!base.success) {
    // Your error message. Invalid mail id
    print('Error Message : ${base.message}'); 
    throw NetworkException(base.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check the interceptor? Catch doesn't seem to be working here.

Comment: I get this now instead of the message: DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: Http status error [401]

Comment: you can manually throw an error based on their type. I don't think any other way @Farwa

Comment: See this DioError class https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/dio/lib/src/dio_error.dart @Farwa